# is it ok to have 2 sitemaps on 1 website?

Tags: sitemap

Do I have to have a sitemap page on my index page for bots to read it or can I just have it anywhere on my server? I have a phpbb/wordpress integration and I need 2 sitemaps mods for each one (or I need to have them somehow integrated together into one xml sitemap).  Is this possible? Whats my best option?

I would have the phpbb one something like this:
   http://www.example.com/phpbb/sitemap.html

and the wordpress one something like this:
   http://www.example.com/wordpress/sitemap.html

and then I would submit both off..but not have the links on my footer to confuse anyone.., the sitemaps would strictly be for search engines. Is this a good idea? what are you thoughts?

Comment: Not a SO programming question - try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing two different types of sitemaps. You mention XML sitemaps but give HTML pages as examples.

An **HTML sitemap** is just a regular web page, like your home page or about page. Search engines do nothing special with them, they just follow all the links as normal.

An **XML sitemap** is a special file created for search robots to read. The [format is explained here](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php). Normal users would not look at this file, but you can submit XML sitemaps to Google Webmaster Tools (and Yahoo and Bing equivalents).

You can submit **as many XML sitemaps as you like**, plus RSS/Atom feeds too. In your case you only have two sitemaps so just go ahead and submit both.

However, if you have many sitemap files, it is usually beneficial to create a **sitemap index file**, which lists all the other sitemaps. See the relevant section on the linked page. Now you only need to submit one file to GWT, and Googlebot will pick up all the other sitemaps. This is also pretty useful if you have a huge site and generate the sitemap files automatically.